# WEBAPI not working when i add server ip address instead of name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, iis

I have created WEBAPI application using VS2017 and deployed into IIS.

After replace my server ip address instead of msweb102 like below URL, i am getting error.

Please help me , if anyone knows the solution. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: i think this is hosting problem. not a code problem.

Comment: is this internal to your company? Also, if you go the IP address and do not put the API details in do you hit IIS at all?

Comment: Also, are you sure thats the right IP and is DNS or your hostfile taking you elsewhere?

Comment: yes. it is for internal purpose. i checked IP address also. this is right.

Comment: but it is working when i use server name, but ip addres it doesnt work.

Comment: IIS can be configured to serve multiple websites from a single IP address. It does this by inspecting the host headers and such sites *cannot* be accessed by IP address alone. It's possible that this is how your site has been configured.

Answer (score 0):

not 100% sure but it should work:

Open the properties from your web.api project and in the Debug tab replace "localhost" with your IP.